# Forcing array to have at least one value in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Is there a Typescript way to require that an array needs to have at least one value? e.g:

```
type value = "1" | "2";

export interface ISomething {
  values: value[] // < should be required and have at least one.
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
type value = "1" | "2";

export interface ISomething {
  values: [value, ...value[]]
}

const empty: ISomething = { values: [] }
// Type '[]' is not assignable to type '[value, ...value[]]'.
// Source has 0 element(s) but target requires 1.

const oneValue: ISomething = { values: ["1"] }
// all good :)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way without interfaces:

```
export type NonEmptyArray<Type> = [Type, ...Array<Type>];
```

Usage:

```
const arrayOfStrings1: NonEmptyArray<string> = ['x']; // valid
const arrayOfStrings2: NonEmptyArray<string> = ['x', 'y']; // valid
const arrayOfStrings3: NonEmptyArray<string> = ['x', 'y', 'z']; // valid
const arrayOfStrings4: NonEmptyArray<string> = [] // invalid
// Type '[]' is not assignable to type '[string, ...string[]]'.
// Source has 0 element(s) but target requires 1.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
type value = "1" | "2";

export interface ISomething {
  values: {
    0: value,
    [key: number]: value,
  }
}``
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also implement an interface that extends `Array`:

```
type value = "1" | "2";

interface IValueArray extends Array<value> {
  0: value; // ensure that at least one 'value' is present
}

export interface ISomething {
  values: IValueArray
}

const something1: ISomething = {
  values: ['1']
}

const something2: ISomething = {
  values: [] // type error
}
```